# Failed to parse field [ DateTime] of type [date]

Tags: python, elasticsearch, types, format, mapping

What should be the format of type DATE while mapping in Elasticsearch 7+ for the date as below:
'2020-09-15 10:08:58.792Z'

I got the same error as below for various date formats. So need a solution to this.

Error: elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', "failed to parse field [Register_DateTime] of type [date] in document with id 'Nd_-j3QBqskwJMqlCHTi'. Preview of field's value: '2020-09-15 10:08:58.792Z'")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default accepted [format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html) is `strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis`, which in your case would be `2020-09-15T10:08:58.792Z`

So, you're just missing the `T` between the date and the time. It's ok, but you need to change your mapping to specify the format, like this:

```
"Register_DateTime": {
    "type": "date",
    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but, still, I am getting the same error.




elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', "failed to parse field [Register_DateTime] of type [date] in document with id 'Nt8jkHQBqskwJMql3XSU'. Preview of field's value: '2020-08-23T10:08:58.792Z'")

Comment: But now you're sending it with a `T`: `2020-08-23T10:08:58.792Z` so the format won't match again

Comment: Still I am getting the same error. Now, to test I changed mapping to:   
             'Register_DateTime': {
                'type': 'date',
                'format': 'yyyy-MM-dd'


and inserted value in same format. Still I got the error as same above. 

elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', "failed to parse field [Register_DateTime] of type [date] in document with id 'Od85kHQBqskwJMqlIHQa'. Preview of field's value: '2020-08-20'")

Comment: Are you sure you're updating the mapping or the right index? Can you share your mapping?

Comment: Thank you bro, silly mistake i was doing, In insertion i was not changing the index name. Now got it. thanks lot. One more thing,     'Customer_ID_UpdateTs':' ' This field is optional field so while inserting data, I am getting error in this due to blank entry. how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out. If the field is empty, you need to set it to null not an empty string